# Display a WebPage using System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser(LightSwitch, VS2012)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have followed;
http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/lightswitchdisplaying-web-pages-html-on-a-screen/

But instead of a webpage im left with;
[image]

Im using VS2012 and the example is in VS2010. The diffrence in code that i have encounterd is the following;

Original;

```
private void WebPage_Activated()
```

Mine;

```
partial void WebPage_Activated()
```

I have checked the debugger and the event fires smoothly, is there any major changes made in beteween the versions or is there anything else that i have overlooked.

I include all code an a picture of where i have put the custom control (im abit uncertain about that part);

```
public partial class WebPage
    {
        partial void WebPage_Activated()
        {
            // Write your code here.
            this.FindControl("prpWebPage").ControlAvailable += webControlAvailable;
        }

        private void webControlAvailable(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            ((System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)e.Control).Navigate(new Uri("http://news.bbc.co.uk"));
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, the size is set to 0 initally. So;

[image]

fixed it :)